# is running a c function an atomic operation in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

Is running a C function an atomic operation in Python?

That is, when we run a C function in a Python-created thread, can the interpreter preempt the GIL from the thread running the C code, then give it to another one? Or must the GIL always be released explicitly using `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` when in C code?

On the opposite side, if we acquire the GIL with `PyGILState_Ensure` from a non-Python thread, can the interpreter preempt the GIL from the thread before we call `PyGILState_Release`? or If the Python function we call does I/O like sending a request, does it release the GIL?

Comment: The GIL remains locked unless the C function releases it, or returns (to Python)

Comment: @Max this is for Python calling a C function right? And from the other direction, if we acquire the GIL with `PyGILState_Ensure` from C code, run a Python function, and in that function do I/O (send a request etc.), GIL is not released? Or if instead of doing I/O, we perform a blocking long running operation, GIL is not preempted by the interpreter?

Comment: If you call back into Python from C, you may be preempted at the usual places that Python will release (eg, most IO is wrapped with Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS).  Make sure your C state is coherent before calling back into a Python function.  You are guaranteed to have the GIL when Python returns to your C code (or if Python calls into your C code).

Comment: @Max great, thanks for the explanation. Is there any documentation you can link to with this info? I could not find this anywhere (mainly, GIL behavior when C code involved)

Comment: I'm not sure all that info is necessarily in one place, but the overview and functions to manipulate it are given in the C-API reference: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock